# How to test form values in react using enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

How can I access and test input fields in react using jest and enzyme?

Container.js

```
import { getAgent } from "../../reducers/agents";
class AgentForm extends Component {
      componentWillMount = () => {
          //code
          this.agent = getAgent(agents, match.params.id);
      }
      render = () => {
       const agent = this.agent;
       return (
              <article className="thirteen wide column">
              <form className="ui form" onSubmit={this.submit}>
              <div className="field">
          <label htmlFor="newFirstName">First Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            tabIndex="10"
            name="newFirstName"
            id="newFirstName"
            placeholder="First Name"
            autoComplete="off"
            autoFocus={true}
            ref={input => (this.firstNameField = input)}
            defaultValue={agent.firstName}
          />
        </div>
        </form>
        </article>
       )
      }
}
```

I want to test the values set in the input field properly.

test.js

```
 it("should set the form values", () => {
     const form = document.createElement("form"),
     store = configureStore(),
     agent = {
              firstName: "agent1",
              lastName: "abc",
              email: "agent1@email.com",
              active: true,
              admin: true
             },
      name = "newAgent";

      const wrapper = shallow(
            <provider store={store}>
            <AgentForm>
            </AgentForm>
            </provider>
      );
     expect(wrapper.find(".ui form").length).toBe(1);
     });
```

But my test fail with following message:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected)

Expected value to be (using ===):
  1
Received:
  0
```

And also I need to test the "defaultValue" field of input is set with "agent1" (ie, from my const agent = { firstName: "agent1" }).  How to pass this test? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use enzyme `mount` not `shallow` when you test nested components. 
Something like:

```
it("should set the form values", () => {
     const form = document.createElement("form"),
     store = configureStore(),
     agent = {
              firstName: "agent1",
              lastName: "abc",
              email: "agent1@email.com",
              active: true,
              admin: true
             },
      name = "newAgent";

  const wrapper = mount(
        <provider store={store}>
           <AgentForm />
        </provider>
  );
 expect(wrapper.find("form").length).toBe(1);
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. But how can i test the given value name = "newAgent" is set into input "name field"?

Comment: You mean  `defaultValue={agent.firstName}` in input tag? I would refactor your test because it not clear where that `agent` comes to use!

Comment: What is your export at `AgentForm` component? And where from `agent.name` comes from?

Comment: export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  //
  
})(AgentForm);  Did you mean this?

Comment: Try to use enzyme `dive` method , `wrapper.dive().find('form')`

Comment: Where do you pass the `agent` and `name` to your mocked store?

Comment: This may help you...
 https://medium.com/@visualskyrim/test-your-redux-container-with-enzyme-a0e10c0574ec